# aligning text in html

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have the following rows in a css file

```
body {text-align: center;}
table {margin: 0 auto}
```

this causes to all text to be aligned to the middle. 
but in somse inner 's I want the text to be aligned right or left
So I added

```
 <table style="text-align:right;">
```

and the text was still centered.
what shoud I add ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code actually works, it's just hard to tell in your example. Take a look at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/UzRdL/

Answer (score 2):

Please add style="text-align:right" with `td`. i think it will be work.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess the table is centered due to the parent div (body). I'll use a div with 100% width and align the text inside it to the right
Or float the div or table to the rigth

Answer (score 1):

If you want only some of the text in the table to be right alignment.

then

```
<table>
<tr>
<td> Text </td>
<td style='text-align:right'>  This text is align to right </td>
<td style='text-align:left'> This text is align to the left </td>
</tr>
</table>
```